# Is there a way to reshape dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to reshape the dataframe in R .

I have a dataframe df as below

```
df <- structure(list(values = c("Man", "4", "AIT", "4"), Inputs = c("id_one", 
"idexp_one", "id_zero", "idexp_zero"), Comp = c("one", "one", 
"zero", "zero")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df
 values     Inputs Comp
1    Man     id_one  one
2      4  idexp_one  one
3    AIT    id_zero zero
4      4 idexp_zero zero
```

Expected output

```
Comp    name   Exp 

one      Man    4
zero     AIT    4
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You should clarify what way you would like to reshape the data as there are multiple ways to end up with the exact same output (see answers below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Comp) %>% summarize(name=max(values), Exp=min(values))
```

or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(name=max(values), Exp=min(values)), Comp]
```

Output:

```
  Comp  name  Exp  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 one   Man   4    
2 zero  AIT   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
  reframe(name = first(values), Exp = last(values), .by = Comp)
  Comp name Exp
1  one  Man   4
2 zero  AIT   4
```

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr only solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(name = lag(values, default = values[1])) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0) %>% 
  select(Comp, name, Exp=values)

  Comp name Exp
1  one  Man   4
2 zero  AIT   4
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

Call `toString` to collapse values column in `summarise` function

Then you can seperate the collapsed column into your specified name using `seperate` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df |> 
  group_by(Comp) |> 
  summarise(values = toString(values)) |> 
  separate(values, sep = ", ", into= c("name", "Exp"))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Comp  name  Exp  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 one   Man   4    
2 zero  AIT   4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see what way you would like to reshape the data having only the output at hand. There are multiple ways to end up with the exact same output. I am assuming here that you would like to separate the values from `values` into two new columns `name` and `Exp` based on whether the column `Input` contains the string "exp":

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    values = c("Man", "4", "AIT", "4"),
    Inputs = c("id_one", "idexp_one", "id_zero", "idexp_zero"),
    Comp = c("one", "one", "zero", "zero")
)

# tidy data
df1 <- df |>
  mutate(type = if_else(str_detect(Inputs, "exp"), "Exp", "name")) |> 
  select(!Inputs)

# reshape wider
df1 |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = values)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Comp  name  Exp  
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 one   Man   4    
#> 2 zero  AIT   4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>